# How can i import excel file from local system using robot framework

Tags: javascript, robotframework

i'm trying to upload excel file from local system using the method Choose File
when i run this code

```
click element    ${btn_upld}
Choose File    //input[@id="upload-i"]  C:/Users/AUTOMATISATION/gm/Import.csv
click element    //*[@value="Upload"]
```

the following error "InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state" is displayed on ride tool
Any help please ?!!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Also - Could we see your HTML which is handling this upload? By the looks of things, theres a button which you press (btn_upld) which then presents you the actually "Browser" upload form? If the form is already there, then you dont need to click the element, just doing `Choose File` is suffice :) But I cant tell till you share your HTML

Comment: i'm using chrome driver i click on "btn_upld" to upload file from my local system

Comment: But I'm wondering what type of form you're using. Because if it is like the one I am thinking of, you don't need to click, simply using the `Choose File` is enough. Could you please show me your HTML snippet which is creating this upload element?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

If your executing it on Windows

```
Choose File    xpath=//input[@id="upload-i"]  C:\\Users\\AUTOMATISATION\\gm\\Import.csv
```

If your executing on linux

```
Choose File    xpath=//input[@id="upload-i"]  C://Users//AUTOMATISATION//gm//Import.csv
```

If there is error let me know